How to run several shortcuts (with delays)
I'm writing a .bat file to run several shortcuts, but they have to be staggered about 10-15 seconds after eachother, for whatever reason sometimes this script doesn't work, even without touching it it stops completely after only 1-3 commands and pauses and I have no idea how to fix it
This is my script
"E:\Users\steve\Desktop\shortcuts\henry.lnk"
timeout /t 15 /nobreak
"E:\Users\steve\Desktop\shortcuts\dad.lnk"
timeout /t 15 /nobreak
"E:\Users\steve\Desktop\shortcuts\eastwardbloom.lnk"
timeout /t 15 /nobreak
"E:\Users\steve\Desktop\shortcuts\judah.lnk"
timeout /t 15 /nobreak
"E:\Users\steve\Desktop\shortcuts\mochab.lnk"
timeout /t 15 /nobreak
"E:\Users\steve\Desktop\shortcuts\mom.lnk"
timeout /t 15 /nobreak
"E:\Users\steve\Desktop\shortcuts\pichupenguin3.lnk"
timeout /t 15 /nobreak
"E:\Users\steve\Desktop\shortcuts\r2pichu.lnk"

it just stops completely usually around the 6th line but it changes every time for some reason.

does some of the shortcuts points to a bat file? You might need to use call directly over the bat file.

Defining a current directory, using a variable, or better, a for loop would shorten that code considerably.

If there is an error with the timeout command you could try to remove that and replace it with:
ping localhost -n 1 >null

And then you can replace the 1 with the time it should wait, the number is not an amount of seconds so you should try some different numbers.
